# R: apriori package/algorithm not working as expected in generating 'confidence' metric

Tags: r, apriori

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
structure(list(CATEGORY = c("Flower", "Flower", "Concentrate,Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Edible,Flower", "Concentrate,Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Edible,Flower", 
"Concentrate,Flower", "Flower", "Edible,Flower", "Flower", "Edible,Flower", 
"Edible,Flower", "Concentrate,Flower", "Flower", "Concentrate", 
"Flower", "Edible,Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Concentrate", 
"Edible,Flower", "Concentrate", "Flower", "Flower", "Concentrate,Flower", 
"Edible,Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Edible,Flower", "Concentrate,Flower", 
"Concentrate", "Concentrate", "Concentrate", "Concentrate", "Edible,Flower", 
"Flower", "Edible,Flower", "Flower", "Concentrate", "Flower", 
"Concentrate,Flower", "Edible,Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Concentrate", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Concentrate", "Concentrate", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Edible,Flower", "Concentrate", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Concentrate", "Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Concentrate", "Flower", "Concentrate,Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Concentrate", 
"Flower", "Concentrate", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Edible,Flower", "Flower", "Concentrate,Flower", "Concentrate,Flower", 
"Flower", "Edible,Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Concentrate,Flower", "Concentrate", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Concentrate,Flower", "Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Concentrate", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Concentrate", "Concentrate,Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Edible,Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Concentrate", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Edible,Flower", "Concentrate", "Flower", 
"Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Concentrate,Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", 
"Edible,Flower")), row.names = c(NA, -200L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

glimpse(interesting_basket_items5)

Rows: 200
Columns: 1
$ CATEGORY <chr> "Flower", "Flower", "Concentrate,Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Flower", "Edible,Flower", "Concentrat…
```

I don't know why the following code using the `arules` package is not working as expected:

```
interesting_basket_items_list <- as(interesting_basket_items5, "transactions")

# mine association rules with the 'apriori' function
rules <- apriori(interesting_basket_items_list, parameter = list(support = 0.001, confidence = 0.05))

# sort the rules by lift
rules <- sort(rules, by = "lift")

# inspect the resulting rules
(rules <- inspect(rules))
```

[image]

The 'support' part of the output looks correct, as checked against my own logic here:

```
interesting_basket_items5 %>%
  group_by(CATEGORY) %>%
  tally() %>%
  mutate(pct = n / sum(n))
```

[image]

But the `confidence` part doesn't make sense to me.

I would think that the confidence of a rule for lhs = {Concentrate} -> rhs {Concentrate, Flower} would have a confidence of `2/3` or `.67` because I am dividing `14` by `21`, which is the number of transactions containing `Concentrate` and `Flower` by the number of transaction containing `Concentrate`

In general, I can't understand why the lhs of these association rules is totally blank like this: `{}` instead of showing a more interesting antecedent. The thresholds that I am using in the code should be inclusive: `parameter = list(support = 0.001, confidence = 0.05))` and the structure of the input data as a list within a list "transactions dataset" I think is correct `{Concentrate}`, `{Concentrate, Flower}` etc

Shouldn't this `rules` dataset have a lhs equal to `Concentrate` and a rhs equal to `{Concentrate, Flower}` with `support = 0.070` and `confidence = 0.67`?

I would like to be able to understand how this is working in terms of probability and conditional probability, in a way where I can demonstrate how it makes sense, start-to-finish, instead of taking data blindly into the `apriori` package and trusting the output, so to speak.

I'd be happy with a solution that shows how to change the structure of data input into `apriori` to get a result that makes sense, or a tuning of the arguments of the `apriori` package, or else I would be happy with a solution that does this in `tidyverse`, some way of implementing the probability that is `support` and the conditional probability that is `confidence` in a way that is comprehensive and easy to demonstrate in the code. I'm just not certain `tidyverse` would easily be comprehensive of all possible permutations of baskets on the conditional probability part, which is probably why the `apriori` package/algorithm was designed...

I'm able to get `apriori` to run but I have my doubts it's really correct for what I want, and I don't know how to coerce anything to make the result more accurate/intuitive, and I also don't know how to reconstruct what `apriori` is doing in `tidyverse`, so I'm stuck. I'd appreciate some kind of answer that could bring this together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the data format: in each row you have just one string which is treated by `apriori` as a transaction, consisting of a single item, where in fact it's a list of items, joined by `,`. Before feeding it to `apriori` you have to split it:

```r
basket_split <- sapply(
  unlist(interesting_basket_items5),
  function(x) strsplit(x, ",")
)
interesting_basket_items_list <- transactions(basket_split)
rules <- apriori(
  interesting_basket_items_list,
  parameter = list(supp = 0.001, conf = 0.05)
)
inspect(rules)
```

Then the output would look right:

```
    lhs              rhs           support confidence coverage lift      count
[1] {}            => {Edible}      0.090   0.09000000 1.000    1.0000000  18  
[2] {}            => {Concentrate} 0.175   0.17500000 1.000    1.0000000  35  
[3] {}            => {Flower}      0.895   0.89500000 1.000    1.0000000 179  
[4] {Edible}      => {Flower}      0.090   1.00000000 0.090    1.1173184  18  
[5] {Flower}      => {Edible}      0.090   0.10055866 0.895    1.1173184  18  
[6] {Concentrate} => {Flower}      0.070   0.40000000 0.175    0.4469274  14  
[7] {Flower}      => {Concentrate} 0.070   0.07821229 0.895    0.4469274  14
```

Comment: I'm seeing also that my interpretation of the conditional probability for confidence is wrong - I should have divided 14 by the sum of 14 and 21 to get 0.4

Comment: Well in your question you got the formula right: "the confidence of a rule for lhs = {Concentrate} -> rhs {Concentrate, Flower} would have a confidence of <...> because I am dividing <...> the number of transactions containing Concentrate and Flower by the number of transaction containing Concentrate".  It's just that you used wrong values because of the split problem.

Comment: so I'm not 100% sure what is happening with your unlist(df) function(x, (strsplit() code section. I actually took the trouble to transform the multiple columns of the dataframe into one column separated by commas:  summarize(CATEGORY = paste(CATEGORY, collapse = ","))) - but all of a sudden you are splitting this back out? It's not so easy to inspect because it's this 'list' object which I'm not so familiar with. But your code seems to work! Although, maybe a little slow on a big dataframe, so I am now splitting the market basket by month groups, which is ok